# Typescript Not Working on MacOS as always installing it shows the below error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, tsc

```
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxyname
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/amandeep/.npm/_logs/2021-11-22T05_50_40_469Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What is the node version? It looks like you're not able to connect to internet registry.npmjs.org. Are you able to install any other module?

Comment: Yes i can access and see version of node as well npm but in case of ts or TSC it is showing this error i cant just install typpescript to my MAC or even IDE

Comment: @RaviKumarGupta Any Suggestions ?

Comment: I am still not getting. Are you able to install any other node pkg?

Comment: yaaa, just cant do typescript. and that is what i want in my Mac, and shows above error @RaviKumarGupta

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.